# When did humans first encounter the Tellarites?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise, first-contact

I'd like to expand (clarify?) [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/2933/7885) made in 2011 by *DVK-on-Ahch-To*. It cites this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romulan#History) article:

> In 2152, Humans made first contact with the Romulans when the Enterprise NX-01 encountered a Romulan-laid minefield. (...) The Romulans saw that **Humans fostered a spirit of cooperation among** the long-belligerent Vulcans, Andorians **and Tellarites** (...).

In the same time the [Tellarite](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tellarite) article in Memory Alpha says:

> In April of 2152, a passing Tellarite vessel directed Enterprise NX-01, suffering severe damage after an encounter in a Romulan minefield, to an automated repair facility.

**When do the Humans made their first contact with the Tellarites?**

I don't recall anything, neither in the Enterprise series, nor anywhere within the franchise, before Romulan minefield incident. If that is true then by no mean could Humans in the same time be already accused of fostering cooperation between Tellarites and any other species because not knowing them so far. This would made [mentioned answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/2933/7885) incorrect, at least in this part.

Note that the [original article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romulan#History) in Wikipedia was edited many times since 2011 and it currently (2019) does not include any of above cited sentences, so I based my question only on [mentioned answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/2933/7885).

Comment: [Here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Romulan&oldid=425043137) is the article as it appeared when that answer was posted, if you want more info ;-)

Comment: To address the apparent contradiction: I doubt that the Romulans were basing their conclusions only on a single audio contact.  That may have alerted them to the fact that there was a new player, but they had spies on Vulcan, and that's how they'd have decided that human peacemaking was a potential threat.  So the old Wikipedia article was writing chronologically, i.e., *first* the NX-01 encountered the Romulans, *then later* the Romulans decided there was a threat - I don't think the intent was to say that Romulans decided there was a threat *while* they were talking to Archer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First contact appears to have been made in 2152. The Enterprise' crew were unaware of the Tellarite race prior to communicating with them.

> **ARCHER:** *What do you know about these Tellarites?*
>
> **T'POL:** *They're not the most agreeable species, but they're usually trustworthy. The co-ordinates are three and a half days away
>   at warp two.*

Note that prior to this the Tellarites were in regular communication with the Vulcans and the Andorians. A new sense of peace between these old enemies would likely pervade the entire region.

---

Interestingly, the [FASA Star Trek: The Roleplaying Game](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Role_Playing_Game_(FASA)) identifies first contact with the Tellarites as early as 2073(!), but this isn't backed up in the shows.

Comment: So first contact with the Tellarites might have happened in 2152 according to all the canon evidence.  But possibly there was an earlier encounter that was not recorded, and someday there might be a novel or episode about that hypothetical earlier encounter, perhaps called "Strangers from the Sty".

Comment: @M.A.Golding - I was thinking *"Close Encounters of the Pork Kind"*